# Making background element absolute in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making some website in bootsrap 3.1, and I have some issues with some element, I know I can make it in picture, but I want admin to allow to change picture and txt. This is how element has to look like

[image]

I want to have picture over the blue element, that I can easy change color in css from blue to red, and opposite. Txt is to must be easy change in `<p>` tag. And on smaller screen I want the picture goes up but all to have blue background and txt to move down under picture. To look like this

[image]

Anyone have some clean css solution in boostrap 3.1?

Comment: Maybe s this a good solution for color??  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,
                                       rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%) top, 
            linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,
                                       rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%) bottom;

Answer (score 0):

You ca use bootstraps column for that

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">your image here</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">your text here</div>
</div>
```

The md-6 column is for your first example (medium and higher) and xs-12 is to have the image stacked on top of the text.

Here's the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Edit: To change the background color, set the background color for small devices and when you want it blue, then change it in the right class (I've used tablets and up in my example):

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */
.yourDiv {background:red}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { .yourDiv {background:blue} }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Don't forget, bootstrap 3 is mobile first.

Comment: This is simple solution when you have two colums, but is I said, i want to change background color from blue to red easy not in picture, than this solution is not oK

Comment: I am not quite following, when exactly do you want to use another background color? When it is on a small device?

Comment: No man, i want to change color from blue to red in css, and on small screen to stay red too, not to change color on different screen

Comment: I updated my comment, hope I understood correctly now.

Comment: O man, please take a look a picture, you will see that image is getting out and bottom of blue element?